# Putting arbitrary content before output of bash time builtin

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printColored(){
  echo -e "\e[0;"$2"m \t"$1" \e[0;37m"
}

printColored "Executing query with usual tables." 34
time hive -f query1.sql
printColored "Executing query with RCFile tables." 34
time hive -f query2.sql
```

It gives me the following output:

```
    Executing query with usual tables. 
...
a lot of output of hive command
...
real    1m8.928s
user    0m36.283s
sys 0m2.157s
    Executing query with RCFile tables. 
...
hive output again
...
real    1m9.376s
user    0m37.186s
sys 0m2.168s
```

**How can I change my script if I need all `hive` output *before* `echo` and time output *after* it?** 
I.e. output must be in the following order:

```
...hive 1...
...hive 2...
    Executing query with usual tables. 
real    1m8.928s
user    0m36.283s
sys 0m2.157s
    Executing query with RCFile tables. 
real    1m9.376s
user    0m37.186s
sys 0m2.168s
```

If this is impossible, how can I eliminate hive output?

Comment: BashFAQ #32 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032 ("How can I redirect the output of 'time' to a variable or a file?") -- is of interest.

Comment: For a simpler answer, `time hive -f query.sql &>/dev/null`; will give you time output, but no hive output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of bash's `time` command can be controlled with the `TIMEFORMAT` shell variable.  To include your desired messages with the usual time information:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'\nExecuting query with usual tables\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys%3lS'
time hive -f query1.sql
TIMEFORMAT=$'\nExecuting query with RCFile tables\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys%3lS'
time hive -f query2.sql
unset TIMEFORMAT
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that time outputs to std error, so you could try to redirect this to a temp file and then display at the end - something like

```
tmpfile=`mktemp`
(time hive -f query1.sql) 2>  $tmpfile
(time hive -f query2.sql) 2>> $tmpfile
cat $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, as given here. You want to have the `time` *inside* the subshell; outside of it, it's not subject to the redirection.

Comment: Much better. You might also think about doing some extra redirection to avoid catching stderr from `hive` as well.